# Select Box with Search Option

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a select dropdown. i need a search in my options. i use select2 dropdown on it but the select not showing the search and the design is completely changed.
[image: this image shows the initial design of the form]
[image: 2nd shows the select dropdown which is not displaying the search]

Here is my code :

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

```
<select class="single" name="icons" onchange="TypeCheck(this);">
    <option value="0">Pick an icon ...</option>
    <option value="1">glass</option>
    <option value="2">door</option>
    <option value="3">Furniture</option>
</select>
```

```
function matchCustom(params, data) {
    if ($.trim(params.term) === '') {
      return data;
    }
    if (typeof data.text === 'undefined') {
      return null;
    }
    if (data.text.indexOf(params.term) > -1) {
      var modifiedData = $.extend({}, data, true);
      modifiedData.text += ' (matched)';
      return modifiedData;
    }
    return null;
}
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.single').select2({
            placeholder: "Select Country",
            allowClear: true,
            matcher: matchCustom
        });
    });
```

Comment: please help me to solve this prblm?

Comment: Hope this helps.. https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/abvmvgK

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined is displaying when i click on select

Comment: I can see the codepen works fine.. Try to reproduce your issue in the codepen provided so that it would be easy to understand your problem..

Comment: Take a look into this https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/gOawPmP

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: text.toUpperCase is not a function

Comment: <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
is else any other scripts needed here?

Comment: Follow the codesandbox provided else create sandbox / fiddle reproducing your issue.. There is no other way to help you in detail unless you make some effort..

Answer (score 1):

You can use select2 default search option rather you want to implement your own search block of code.

```
<select class="yourClassName" name="states[]" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    ...
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

and you can use select2 default jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.yourClassName').select2();
});
```

you can visit this link for more details https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage

Comment: i not need multpile select